# please provide a value for APP_BASE_HREF token exception Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am developing the first Angular 2 application and have the following code

**AppModule.ts code**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent} from './home/menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent} from './home/footer/footer.component';
import { AboutComponent} from './personalDetails/about/about.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:  [ 
              BrowserModule,
              RouterModule.forRoot([
                  {path: '' , component : AboutComponent},
                  {path: 'about' , component : AboutComponent}

                ])
            ],
  declarations: [ 
                AppComponent, 
                MenuComponent, 
                FooterComponent,
                AboutComponent,


                ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent.ts** code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template:   `
                <menu></menu>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                <footer></footer>

                `

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

My console says the following error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is simple and I forgot to add the base href tag in the index.html,

```
<base href="/"/>
```

When I researched why should we add base href by default which is not the case in angular1. I found the following

1. By **default** Angular2 uses **HTML5**
2. No hash symbol is needed.
3. URL Rewriting is necessary, if the application runs in any of the server which are different for each server and can be found in the documentation which are separate for [**Tomcat**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html), **[IIS](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)** etc.