# Why every time this error shows when I run ng serve my project?

Tags: angular, angular-errorhandler

> error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF
>   token or add a base element to the document. at new
>   PathLocationStrategy (common.js:453) at provideLocationStrategy
>   (router.js:5547) at *callFactory (core.js:21286) at
>   createProviderInstance (core.js:21238) at initNgModule (core.js:21168)
>   at new NgModuleRef (core.js:21895) at createNgModuleRef
>   (core.js:21884) at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as
>   createNgModuleRef] (core.js:23715) at
>   NgModuleFactory*.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create
>   (core.js:24419) at core.js:17765

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [please provide a value for APP\_BASE\_HREF token exception Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526912/please-provide-a-value-for-app-base-href-token-exception-angular2)

Answer (score 2):

As per your error trace, it looks like base href is undefined. Try adding `<base href="/">` in index.html.

**Index.html**

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- other code-->
</head>
```

Hope, this helps

Comment: Please click the tick for this comment, for marking this issue as answered.

Answer (score 1):

A predefined DI token for the base href to be used with the PathLocationStrategy. The base href is the URL prefix that should be preserved when generating and recognizing URLs.

```
const APP_BASE_HREF: InjectionToken<string>;
```

The following example shows how to use this token to configure the root app injector with a base href value, so that the DI framework can supply the dependency anywhere in the app.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```